# Removing commas from an array with strings and empty spaces going to an email

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

In google sheets i have merged 4 cells into 1 and then i put the entered text data of that cell into an array position.  When i call that array position and try to place it into an email body, i get 3 extra commas on the end of the string.

How can i remove the commas or merge the data into 1 item?

My merged cell string text is in position 15.
When i drop that data into the email, it will say:  Data is here,,,

I tried slice, join & replace, but none of them worked.

```
var incidentsum  = data[15];
var newincident  = incidentsum.slice(0, incidentsum.length - 3);
var newincident  = incidentsum.join(" ");
incidentsum.replace(/,/g, "")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is`data[15]` ?

Comment: data[15] is the merged cell's data such as an entry that says: My Response is HERE. It's a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a regex ($ means end of the line):

```
var incidentsum  = data[15]; //Data is here,,,
var newincident = incidentsum.replace(/,,,$/, ''); //Data is here
```

Comment: I tried text.replace and it said text was not defined.

Comment: I also tried to place incident sum into the position of text  (incidentsum.replace(); and that provided this error: TypeError: incidentsum.replace is not a functionDetails.

Comment: It worked once i dropped the email's body into that expression in place of text